# Dividing two integers in Java gives me 0 or 100?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to divide two integers and multiply by 100 but it keeps giving only 0 or 100. Can someone help me?

```
    int x= (a/b)*100;
```

if a was 500 and b was 1000 it would give me 0. The only time it will give me 100 is if a>=b. How can I fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Please explain the expected result.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

What you could do is force it to divide `a` and `b` as doubles thus:

```
int x = (int) (((double) a / (double) b) * 100);
```

Comment: This one is missing a cast to `int`. Otherwise it will not compile.

Comment: Please accept as answer as it will raise this answer to the top and help others, thanks.

Answer (score 10):

Integer division has no fractions, so 500 / 1000 = 0.5 (that is no integer!) which gets truncated to integer 0. You probably want

```
int x = a * 100 / b;
```

Comment: But be aware that this approach might overflow.

Comment: unless you cast your ints as long first

Answer (score 6):

This sounds like you are not correctly typing your variables; two integer divisions result in an integer, not a float or double. For example:

```
(int)3 / (int)5 = 0
(float)3 / (float)5 = 0.6
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
int x = a * 100 / b;
```

The idea is, you are first doing `a / b`, and because it's an integer operation, it'll round the result to `0`. Doing `a * 100` first should fix it.

Comment: But be aware that this approach might overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest, most effective way I found:

```
double x = (double) a / (double) b
```

Comment: correct answer, though I'd think it even more helpful to explain how integer division caused this issue