# Android: Division and subtraction always equal 1.0

Tags: java, android, calculator, arithmetic-expressions

I'm making a simple calculator but when I try to divide I always get 1.0 and when I subtract I always get zero. Addition and multiplication work fine.

I've read similar questions such as :
[Why does integer division code give the wrong answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7286681/why-does-my-java-division-code-give-the-wrong-answer)
[Dividing two integers in Java gives me 0 or 100?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8669854/dividing-two-integers-in-java-gives-me-0-or-100)
[Division in Java always results in zero (0)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10455677/division-in-java-always-results-in-zero-0)

and many more...

Here is a part of my code :

```
 if (minu) {
    number1 = Double.valueOf(display1.getText().toString());
    number2 = Double.valueOf(display1.getText().toString());

    display1.setText("");
    display2.setText("");
    displaySymbol.setText("");

    answer = number1 - number2;

    display1.setText(Double.toString(answer));
 }
```

and the division:

```
if (divid) {
    number1 = Double.valueOf(display1.getText().toString());
    number2 = Double.valueOf(display1.getText().toString());

    display1.setText("");
    display2.setText("");
    displaySymbol.setText("");

    answer = number2  / number1;

    display1.setText(Double.toString(answer));
}
```

Please help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are reading the value from `display1` **twice**, you forgot to change the  reading of `number2` to `display2`.

---

Replace:

```
number2 = Double.valueOf(display1.getText().toString());
```

with

```
number2 = Double.valueOf(display2.getText().toString());
```

---

Your function would end up being:

```
if(minu){
    number1 = Double.valueOf(display1.getText().toString());
    number2 = Double.valueOf(display2.getText().toString());

    display1.setText("");
    display2.setText("");
    displaySymbol.setText("");

    answer = number1 - number2;

    display1.setText(Double.toString(answer));
}
```