# convert milliliters to liters, show 0,4 liters instead of 400 mililiters

Tags: android

I have something like this:

```
int mls = 400; // 400 milliliters
```

I'd like to show 0,4 for users (0,4... 0,8... 1,0 ... 1,2...)

I try to divide `mls` by 1000:

```
mls = 400 / 1000;

TextView todayValue = findViewById(R.id.todayValue);
        todayValue.setText(String.valueOf(mls));
```

it gives me 0 as a result.

any ideas how to convert milliliters to liters showing to user something like `0,4 liters`???

Answer (score 2):

The idea is, you are first doing a / b, and because it's an integer operation, it'll round the result to 0. Doing a * 100 first should fix it.

From:[Dividing two integers in Java gives me 0 or 100?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8669854/dividing-two-integers-in-java-gives-me-0-or-100/8669902)

Answer (score 2):

You should try it with another primitive type since `int` doesn't cover decimals.

Other options are, for instance, `Double`, `Float`, `Long`

So instead of declaring your variable as `int mls = 400` you could do it as `double mls = 400`.

Another solution could be using a decimal at the operation, like `400.0 / 1000.0`